# Issue in using FTP Connection in Informatica

Tags: informatica

FTP connection object in my Workflow, However, while executing for few minutes it is getting failed throwing an error : '
A socket [29] failure is encountered: [Connection reset by peer].

Answer (score 0):

Might be getting a timeout on the ftp server after inactivity

Comment: Have you tried ssh or telnet from the Informatica server to the ftp server on the same host and port settings that you configured in workflow manager connections?